# Emails send to Yahoo declined

Tags: server, email, postfix, vps

I recently set up purchased a VPS, installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it and Webmin/Virtualmin. I think I configured DNS records for each domain I've added properly.

When I am sending emails to an Yahoo email I receive the following error:

```
C658BA3706      565 Wed Jan 29 15:13:47  nedegroup@nedegroup.com
(host mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.217.202] said: 421 4.7.1 [TS03] All messages from 188.226.139.41 will be permanently deferred; Retrying will NOT succeed. See http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts03.html (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

How can I solve this problem? I do not intent to send bulk/spam email.

Is there a way to make all my email accounts created on different domain names under my VPS to send emails to the Inbox folder of other email accounts?

For example when I send to gmail my emails go to inbox, but when I send to hotmail they go to the spam folder.

Thanks

Comment: create spf record otherwise yahoo / hotmail wont accept your mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain isn't on the major blacklists and there's no problem with your SMTP server or settings (you've got it set rather well, actually). You will have to sort out your issue with sending to Yahoo email addresses with the support people at Yahoo as it is their blocking policy that's preventing delivery. Given their recent security issues, this may not be a surprising outcome of their trying to lock down their systems...

For the Gmail vs. Hotmail issue, it's probably their respective mail filtering algorithms that result in the Inbox vs. Spam folder issue. Again, that's something you would have to work out with Hotmail support.

Comment: I am not an expert in linux, DNS and stuff like this. I'm quite a newbie. Do you think I have everything well configured for www.nedegroup.com and www.nutrizzio.com, I mean their DNS records.

Comment: Only thing I see is that you have the same machine listed for two name server entries. Ideally you want separate machines acting as your name servers in case one fails. Other than that, looks okay.

Comment: @AdrianGeorge I checked Yahoo's documentation on this.  [You should start by reading this link here](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN3436.html?impressions=true) because it explains why you're seeing that error.  Specifically it indicates that "Yahoo is seeing a high volume of emails from your IP address, which is a characteristic of unsolicited, bulk emailing."

Comment: @ThomasW. Which has to be some funky Yahoo policy because his domain/IP wasn't on **any** of the big RBLs. And it will take working with Yahoo directly to get off their block list. He had good reverse DNS, which is one of the few things Yahoo stated as a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo Help page for that error is: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail/SLN3437.html?impressions=true

Since it is a new server you just set up, it probably doesn't have any complaints. What are the chances the IP address was previously used by someone with a mail server that generated complaints?

Also, if you're sending out emails that look like spam to a computer (even if they're actually legitimate), that will play a part in the rejection. Stuff like hyperlinks with little text in the body.